# Detect when all Shiny inputs/outputs are bound?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I want to wait to run some Javascript until after all Shiny inputs and outputs have been bound.

One way to do this is to listen for the 'shiny:bound' event X times, where X is the sum of the inputs and outputs, and is known in advance. (http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/js-events.html)

But I know I'll forget to change X if I add or remove an input/output, so I'm trying to do this more abstractly.

Is there a concise way to check, either from server.R or in a JS script, whether Shiny has finished all of its binding, without knowing exactly how many inputs/outputs there are?

Note the 'shiny:idle' even often fires before everything is bound, so I don't think that will work.

Comment: It might be easier to just wait some time using shinyjs::delay (https://github.com/daattali/shinyjs)

Comment: Thanks, yeah, my current workaround is just using setTimeout, but it's impossible to know whether a given amount of time is enough for all browsers and use cases, which led me down this path. Might not be possible though.